# Spring Thymeleaf classappend not appending the classes

Tags: java, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to classappend a few classes dependant on errors found in the validation process of a form. But for some reason, it's not appending the classes. My CSS is correct as it works without using the classappend error check and also my validation is correct as it will detect an error in the form but just won't append the css classes. The specific method used is updateRole() in the RoleController class. Below is all my code:

RoleController.java

```
@Controller
public class RoleController {

    @Autowired
    private RoleServiceImpl roleService;

    @RequestMapping("/roles")
    public String viewAllRoles(ModelMap model) {
        List<Role> roles = roleService.findAll();
        model.put("roles", roles);

        if (!model.containsAttribute("role")) {
            model.put("role", new Role());
        }

        return "roles";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addRole(@Valid Role role, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // Add the error message as a flash attribute
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.role", result);
            // Add the role object created so the user can see their inital input after redirect
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("role", role);

            return "redirect:/roles";
        }

        roleService.save(role);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Role successfully added", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));


        return "redirect:/roles";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles/{roleId}")
    public String viewRole(@PathVariable Long roleId, ModelMap model) {
        Role role = roleService.findById(roleId);
        model.put("role", role);

        return "role";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles/{roleId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateRole(@Valid Role role, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.role", result);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("role", role);
            return String.format("redirect:/roles/%s/edit", role.getId());
        }

        roleService.save(role);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage("Role successfully updated", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));

        return "redirect:/roles";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles/{roleId}/edit")
    public String editRole(@PathVariable Long roleId, ModelMap model) {
        Role role = roleService.findById(roleId);
        model.put("action", String.format("/roles/%s", roleId));
        model.put("role", role);

        return "role_edit";
    }

}
```

role_edit.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:replace="base :: head('role_edit')"></head>
    <body>
        <header th:replace="base :: header"></header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a th:href="@{projects}">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a th:href="@{collaborators}">Collaborators</a></li>
                <li class="selected"><a th:href="@{roles}">Roles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section>
            <div class="container wrapper">
                <form th:action="@{${action}}" method="post" th:object="${role}">
                    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
                    <div class="edit-input" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'edit-error test' : ''">
                        <label> Role Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}">
                    </div>
                    <div th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'error' : ''">
                        <div class="testtwo error-message" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">Save</button>
                        <a th:href="@{|/roles/*{id}|}" class="button button-secondary">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help it would be great, as I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: Start by inserting a `span th:text="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"` (the Thymeleaf equivalent of a println) and see what that says. (Also consider using Thymeleaf Layout Dialect to manage your page layouts.)

Comment: @chrylis I added what you said, and the text constantly reads "false" before an error and after the error is found

Comment: There you go, that's your starting point. Figure out why it's false. (In the most extreme case, run in debug mode, put a breakpoint in `BindingResult#hasErrors(String)`, and look at the result state there.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out was a stupid mistake of mine @chrylis

Comment: @Daniel next time you can share your mistake so others can learn from it too  : )